# Find the limit of the following series $x_n$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$, where: $$x_n = \sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{4n^2+2n}-\sqrt[3]{27n^3+n^2}.$$ I am completely clueless about what should I do here, every attempt to solve it led me from $\infty - \infty$ to $\infty * 0$, which is even worse. Please, any small hint regarding how should I proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think an asymptotic expansion of $x_n$ will be the easiest way to go.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Series or sequence ?

Comment: extract $n$ from each term and use the taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ at $x=0$.

Comment: $x_n$ is a sequence and *not* a series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First factor out the highest power of $n$ in each term:

$x_n=n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}+2n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2n}}-3n\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{27n}}$

This now puts each expression under each root sign into the form $1+t$ where $t$ will be small as $n \to \infty$, so we can use the binomial theorem, and "..." will represent terms in $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and higher that will tend to zero as $n \to \infty$:

$x_n=\large n\{(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{1/2}+2(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{1/2}-3(1+\frac{1}{27n})^{1/3}\}$

$x_n=\large n\{(1+\frac12\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}+...)+2(1+\frac12\cdot\frac{1}{2n}+...)-3(1+\frac13\cdot\frac{1}{27n}+...)\}$

If you tidy that up you should obtain $x_n = $ (constant) $+$ (terms in $1/n$ and higher).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You can split in two indeterminate expressions,

$$\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{n^3+\frac{n^2}{27}}+2\left(\sqrt{n^2+\frac n2}-\sqrt[3]{n^3+\frac{n^2}{27}}\right).$$

Now use

$$a-b=\frac{a^6-b^6}{a^5+a^4b+a^3b^2+a^2b^3+ab^4+b^5}$$ on the two limits separately, and notice that all terms in the denominator are asymptotic to $n^5$. There is no need to compute all terms in the numerators, only sixth and fifth degree.

---

> $$\frac{n^6+\cdots-n^6-\dfrac{2n^5}{27}-\cdots}{6n^5}+2\frac{n^6+\dfrac{3n^5}2+\cdots-n^6-\dfrac{2n^5}{27}-\cdots}{6n^5}\to\frac{25}{54}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: I've downvoted because I started working through the details of your solution - it's clever, but it's a lot of work. (I know you don't have to expand to every term, but you still need to produce a fair number of terms, and you have to do it twice!)  I feel that the answer I have posted is less work and takes a more "obvious" route.

Comment: @MilesB: thank you for the explanation. I have added a spoiler that shows which terms really need to be computed. They are essentially the same as yours. This solution only uses algebra.

Comment: Your spoiler hides a fair bit of thinking on the denominator.  For example, if a = sqrt(n^2+1) then a^5 = n^5 (sqrt(1 + 1/n^2))^5 and it's not immediately obvious that the denominator builds up to 6 terms of the form n^5 * (1 + terms in 1/n, 1/n^2, ...)

Comment: @MilesB: a polynomial is asymptotic to its leading term, hence the four roots are asymptotic to $n$. That's immediate. Hence my comment "all terms in the denominator are asymptotic to $n^5$." It is also immediate that the question has been arranged in such a way that the $n^6$ (in my numerators) cancel out. There are essentially two coefficients to compute from powers of binomials (because the first binomial yields no $n^5$, and two binomials are identical). In fact, you can solve mentally.